# How to go back to the start of a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use the methods `Skip()` and `Take()` to get values from a list. But I can't manage to go back to the start of the list when the list ends.

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Duck1");
list.Add("Duck2");
list.Add("Duck3");
list.Add("Duck4");
list.Add("Duck5");

var list2 = list.Skip(4).Take(3);

foreach(var a in list2) {
  Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

The result is:

- Duck5

The result that I'm looking for is:

- Duck5
- Duck1
- Duck2

Comment: `Last` and `First` can also be used here. `Console.WriteLine(list.First()); Console.WriteLine(list.Last());`

Comment: You could implement a circular list collection (.NET doesn't have one built-in) with an enumerator that loops back to the head after it returns the tail.

Comment: @Igor that will not work if i change the Take to 3...

Comment: I did not say anything about `Take`. You *initially* wrote you wanted `Duck5` and `Duck1`, that accomplishes that request.

Comment: I'm not sure why you called your `IEnumerable<string>` `index`. My fear is that you have a misunderstanding about what's going on in your code. You can't do what you're trying to with standard LINQ on a `List<T>`.

Comment: @itsme86 was a random name edited in question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a method that will make an `IEnumerable<T>` circular and then use that.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToCircular<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    while(true)
    {
        foreach(var x in source) yield return x;
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Duck1");
list.Add("Duck2");
list.Add("Duck3");
list.Add("Duck4");
list.Add("Duck5");

var list2 = list.ToCircular().Skip(4).Take(3);

foreach(var a in list2){
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

But be careful as this results in an infinite loop and you'd want to limit it when using it with `Take` or `TakeWhile` or `First`.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that you're only going to need to "loop back" once, and you can simply use Concat:

```
var list2 = list.Concat(list).Skip(4).Take(3);
```

Otherwise I suggest [juharr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61484500/120955). Just be aware that you need to be really careful with infinite IEnumerables. Many LINQ operations that need to consume the whole collection (e.g. `.ToList()`, `.Reverse()`, `.OrderBy()`) will freeze up your application and cause it to run out of memory.

Comment: yeah, i will need to loop more than once, thks anyway for the effort